# Is there a way to have a random image appear every time an item spawns? (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on a sprite-kit game for IOS. In my game, I have pieces of debris spawn every 5 seconds,  then move towards the player, like obstacles. I made a series of images for the debris I wanted to use, but can't seem to figure out how to randomly spawn them in the game?

This is my code:

```
-(void)spawnDebris {
    SKSpriteNode * debris = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"debrisPiece1.png"] size:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];

    debris.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10];
    debris.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO; //might say yes
    debris.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionDebris;
    debris.position = CGPointMake(50, 50);

    [_debris addObject:debris];
    [self addChild:debris];

    //next Spawn:
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
             [SKAction waitForDuration:5],
             [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnDebris) onTarget:self],                                  
    ]]];
}
```

Where the parent "`_debris`" is an `NSMutableArray * _debris`. How would I go about writing it so that I can have debrisPiece 2 or debrisPiece 3 (images of debris) spawn too? Do I make another array inside the `spriteNodeWithTexture:@[]`?? Is that even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a random number using the arc4random() function, so you can do it like this:

```
NSString *base = @"debrisPiece";
uint32_t num = arc4random_uniform(number_of_debris_images) + 1; //Generate a random number
NSString *textureName = [base stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d.png", num];
SKSpriteNode * debris = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:textureName] size:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
//...
```

Comment: uint32_t num = arc4random_uniform(number_of_debris_images) + 1;

Comment: Thanks, edited.  I completely forgot about arc4random_uniform().